# Freeform: pass variable to confirmation page

Tags: solspace-freeform, php, forms, variable

I have a freeform form with a text field with a value.  Users of this form are not logged in and I need to pass the value of that field to a second confirmation page where I am building a paypal form.  The passed value represents the amount to pay in the paypal form.

So on the Freeform:

```
<input name="amount" type="text" id="Amount" size="8" placeholder="$ amount"/>
```

and on the confirm page in a paypal form

```
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{amount}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the entry_id in your return parameter.

```
return="group/template/%%entry_id%%
```

then use the freeform entries tag and specify entry_id="{segment_3}"
with that you can then pull any data that was submitted.

```
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{segment_3}"}
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{amount}" />
...anything else you want to display from the submission
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Comment: I just tried that and the entry_id is passing to segment_3 but nothing is being posted for {amount}

Comment: Did you check in the Freeform CP and see if there was any data entered in the database? Is {amount} the correct variable name?  Could be one of a couple of things? Also check the status of the entry. Is it "pending".  if so you will need to add the status="pending" parameter. It defaults to open only.

Comment: yes the entry is there in submissions.  amount has a value, and yes I already added status="pending"

Comment: Do any of you other fields output data?
Is {amount} the correct field name?
Try setting the form_id="xx" parameter as well.
What versions of EE & FF?

Comment: EE 2.11.3 FF 4.2.5
`
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{segment_3}" status="pending" form_id="3" }
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{amount}" />
{amount}{entry_id} {name}
{/exp:freeform:entries}`

output: {amount}{entry_id} {name}

segment 3 is correct.  it is the enty id of the form entry

Comment: So these just show the tag? {amount}{entry_id} {name}

Comment: that is right.  they only show the tag.  Nothing is parsed.  The curly quotes and the field name display and not the contents of the fields.

Comment: Try turning on template debugging and see if it has any information on the tag. Something's not right, not sure what to tell you at this point unless you want to give me a login to your site.